# How to remove item from list based on attribute comparison?

Tags: java

I have a list of objects "Artical" which have 2 attributes articalid and articalVersion
as shown below.

```
enter public class Artical{
public int articalid;
public double articalVersion;
//with getter and setters
}
```

and now have list having following result

```
articalid=1098  articalVersion=1.0
articalid=1098  articalVersion=1.1
articalid=1078  articalVersion=1.0
articalid=1078  articalVersion=1.1
articalid=1065  articalVersion=1.0
articalid=1043  articalVersion=1.0
```

now I want to make list that contain only that objects that have greater version no.(and articalid must not repeat ) like

```
articalid=1098  articalVersion=1.1
articalid=1078  articalVersion=1.1
articalid=1065  articalVersion=1.0
articalid=1043  articalVersion=1.0
```

Comment: Let us know what have you tried.

Comment: use an iterator to iterate over your existing list and remove the elements as per your requirement.

Comment: i get list of artical from database which contain articalid ,articalversion and some description attribute ...... but i need to get latest version only ...as you see my list contain all version with same artical id ....i need only latest version from that list..

Comment: @Zeeshan give some example or some link to do so ...

Comment: @Usman - can you use Java 8 syntax? It has great stream and filter features for this kind of thing.

Comment: @tbsalling i am using java 6 . any solution for java 6

Comment: @UsmanHayatKhan, I have provided some code. Check it and let me know if u have any issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you sort your List

```
Collections.sort(articleList, new ArticalComparatorSort());
```

By using the following comparator:

```
class ArticalComparatorSort implements Comparator<Artical>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Artical a1, Artical a2)
    {
        if(a1.getArticalid() < a2.getArticalid()){
            return -1;
        }
        else if(a1.getArticalid() > a2.getArticalid()){
            return  1;
        }
        else{ // When both id are equals
            return Double.compare(a2.getArticalVersion(), a1.getArticalVersion());
        }
    }

}
```

This will sort as:

```
[1043 : 1.0
, 1065 : 1.0
, 1078 : 1.1
, 1078 : 1.0
, 1098 : 1.1
, 1098 : 1.0
```

Then use a `TreeSet` to remove duplicates

```
Set<Artical> mySet = new TreeSet<Artical>(new ArticalComparatorSet());
```

For `TreeSet` use the following comperator:

```
class ArticalComparatorSet implements Comparator<Artical>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Artical a1, Artical a2)
    {
        if(a1.getArticalid() < a2.getArticalid()){
            return -1;
        }
        else if(a1.getArticalid() > a2.getArticalid()){
            return  1;
        }
        else{ 
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

This will remove duplicates as:

```
[1043 : 1.0
, 1065 : 1.0
, 1078 : 1.1
, 1098 : 1.1
```

So you need to add only these three lines of code for removing duplicates:

```
Collections.sort(articleList, new ArticalComparatorSort());

Set<Artical> mySet = new TreeSet<Artical>(new ArticalComparatorSet());

mySet.addAll(articleList);
```

> *And only implement the above comparators*

Comment: This code is very helpful to me .now working fine and now i have list of latest version of articals.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do like this over an iteration

```
         Map<Integer,Artical> outPuts = new HashMap<Integer,Artical>();
 for(Artical artical1 : articals ){
     for(Artical artical2 : articals ){
             if(artical1.getarticalid() == artical2.getarticalid()){
             int retval = Double.compare(artical1.getarticalVersion(), artical2.getarticalVersion());
             if(retval > 0) {
                 if(outPuts.containsKey(artical1.getarticalid())){
                     outPuts.remove(artical1.getarticalid());
                     outPuts.add(artical1.getarticalid(),artical1);
                 }else{
                     outPuts.add(artical1.getarticalid(),artical1);
                 }
                 }
             else{
                 if(outPuts.containsKey(artical1.getarticalid())){
                     outPuts.remove(artical1.getarticalid());
                     outPuts.add(artical1.getarticalid(),artical1);
                 }else{
                     outPuts.add(artical1.getarticalid(),artical1);
                 }
                 }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: so you say that we compare version of artical (after artical id check)
if we have articalVerison 1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3 , 1.4 , 1.5 then we need 1.5 but how your code can reture object with 1.5 by comparing that ?